# Multicolor Multiline TMemo

Tags: delphi

**Is it possible to configure Multicolor Multiline TMemo in Delphi XE2?**.
When I am writing codes like :

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FirstVariable, SecondVariable, ThirdVariable :BOOL;
begin
  if FirstVariable then
    begin
      Memo1.Font.Color := clGreen;
      Memo1.Lines.Add('FirstVariable = True');
    end
  else if SecondVariable then
    begin
      Memo1.Font.Color := clBlue;
      Memo1.Lines.Add('SecondVariable = True');
    end
  else
    begin
      Memo1.Font.Color := clRed;
      Memo1.Lines.Add('ThirdVariable = True');
    end;
end;
```

font color for all the previously existing lines are getting changed according to condition of the variables.

Comment: Please remove `= true`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it is not possible. But you can use a RICHEDIT control instead, e.g., the `TRichEdit` wrapper.

```
RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clGreen;
RichEdit1.Lines.Add('First line.');

RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clBlue;
RichEdit1.Lines.Add('Second line.');

RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clRed;
RichEdit1.Lines.Add('Third line.');
```

Comment: I think that technically it is possible (haven't tried) by doing direct drawing to the canvas. However that's way more than is necessary, a rich edit is meant for this.